# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException Allatori error

Tags: java, obfuscation, bukkit, java-16, allatori

Hey I am using this obfuscator http://www.allatori.com/ and I get a weird error that I am confused on how to fix. Its looks like the problem is located at the obfuscated jar spot and not the normal source file which confuses me. I think it might have something to do with Allatori config.

Error:
`

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at com.allatori.IiiIIiIIii.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.allatori.IiiIIiIIii.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.allatori.iIiiiIIIII.E(nv:688)
        at com.allatori.iIiiiIIIII.E(nv:151)
        at com.allatori.iIiiiIIIII.E(nv:654)
        at com.allatori.iiIIIIIiIi.A(rs:385)
        at com.allatori.iiIIIIIiIi.C(rs:235)
        at com.allatori.Obfuscate.H(jz:865)
        at com.allatori.Obfuscate.main(jz:420)
```

`

POM:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>xyz.interglacticdev</groupId>
    <artifactId>SMPAdmin</artifactId>
    <version>DEVELOPMENT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-and-filter-allatori-config</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${basedir}/allatori</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>allatori.xml</include>
                                    </includes>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>run-allatori</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>java</executable>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>-Xms128m</argument>
                        <argument>-Xmx512m</argument>
                        <argument>-jar</argument>

                        <!-- Copy allatori.jar to 'allatori' directory to use the commented line -->
                        <argument>${basedir}\allatori\lib\allatori.jar</argument>
                        <!-- <argument>${basedir}/allatori/allatori.jar</argument> -->

                        <argument>${basedir}/allatori/defaultconfig.xml</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <!-- This adds the Spigot Maven repository to the build -->
        <repository>
            <id>spigot-repo</id>
            <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <name>jcenter</name>
            <id>bintray-jcenter</id>
            <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </repository>

    </repositories>



    <dependencies>
        <!--This adds the Spigot API artifact to the build -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
            <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>club.minnced</groupId>
            <artifactId>discord-webhooks</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.8</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Allatori Config:

```
<keep-names>
    <class access="private+">
        <field access="private+"/>
        <method access="private+"/>
    </class>
</keep-names>

<property name="random-seed" value="a"/>
<watermark key="secure-key-to-extract-watermark" value="a"/>
<property name="log-file" value="log.xml"/>
<property name="string-encryption" value="disable"/>
<property name="string-encryption-type" value="fast"/>
<property name="string-encryption-version" value="v4"/>
    <property name="synthetize-methods" value="disable"/>
    <property name="synthetize-fields" value="disable"/>
<property name="control-flow-obfuscation" value="disable"/>
<property name="extensive-flow-obfuscation" value="disable"/>
<property name="local-variables-naming" value="keep"/>
<property name="skip-renaming" value="enable"/>
<property name="line-numbers" value="keep"/>
<property name="generics" value="keep"/>


<classpath basedir="D:\Spigot\SMPAdmin]\library-jars\lib">
    <jar name="*.jar"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: We can't debug what we can't reproduce. Also not to taunt you, but there's definitely some irony in the obfuscator you're using preventing you from understanding what's happening in your code.

Comment: @Siguza Is there some way I could make it easier to understand

Comment: Presumably by not running it through the obfuscator.

Comment: Yeah but the obfuscator is causing the problem